# @Multipart of cxf contains header information inside the file

Tags: rest, postman, jax-rs, cxf, multipart

I am sending a file using postman to a server where I have written my file upload webservice

Here is the code:

```
 @POST
@Path("/uploadAssets")
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void uploadAssets(@Multipart(value ="file") InputStream inputStream, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
```

I am using form-data in postman to send the file.
HEADER info:
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary= calculated when request is sent

I copied the file that was received by the server. When I check its contents, I get this at the top:

----------------------------390134122734517341539891^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="beach2.jpg"^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
^M

When I delete the above header information that is getting added to the binary, I can see the image being rendered on the server. I tried using MultipartBody but was getting unsupported mime type error. Can anyone please help me out?

Also, I am getting NullpointerException when using formdataparam

```
   @POST
    @Path("/uploadAssets")
     @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void uploadAssets(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition filFormDataContentDisposition, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        try {
```

Comment: Also, I am getting nullpointer exception when I use FormDataParam

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use MultipartFile like this;

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadAssets")
@Consumes(MediaType..MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void uploadAssets(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
```